# Convolution Neural Net for Stock Market Prediction, Regression

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am working on a stock market prediction project using sentiment analysis. I am trying to create a CNN model where I am passing 4000 days of stock data with a batch size of 100. At the end of the dense layer, I want to add regression layer to get the price of the stock.

```
def Model(train_data):
input_layer = tf.reshape(tf.cast(train_data, tf.float32), [-1, 1, 100, 2])
conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=input_layer,filters=32,kernel_size=[1, 5],padding="same",
                     activation=tf.nn.relu,strides=1,kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer())
pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1, pool_size=[1, 2], strides=[1,2])
conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=pool1,filters=8,kernel_size=[1, 5],padding="same",activation=tf.nn.relu,
                    strides=1,kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer())
pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2, pool_size=[1, 5], strides=[1,5])
conv3 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=pool2,filters=2,kernel_size=[1, 2],padding="same",activation=tf.nn.relu,
                    strides=1,kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer())
pool3 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv3, pool_size=[1, 2], strides=[1, 2])
pool3_flat = tf.reshape(pool3, [40, 1 * 5 * 2])
dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool3_flat, units=5, activation=tf.nn.relu)
dropout = tf.layers.dropout(
  inputs=dense, rate=0.2, training=mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)
logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=1)
```

I am referring https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimators/cnn for the model, but they are doing classification. Can anybody suggest an approach for regression? The train_data for the model has a shape of [2,4000] where one row is for normalized stock prices and another is for sentiment factor.

Comment: what shape is your output?

Comment: The logits layer will be of shape [40,1]

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you would have to do would be to add a fully connected layer at the very end, and select a linear activation.  Intuitively, this will take the outputs of your Conv layers, and apply y = mx + b to them.  Your fully connected output layer would have 40 nodes (one for each output).  In fact, you already have one dense layer in that code.  If your output is of size 40, just make it 40 instead of 5.

Just a side note, traditionally, CNNs are used for image classification, and only recently did it start migrating to other applications (such as spam detection).  I would advise trying a simple feed forward neural network first, and if that does not work, perhaps try a RNN before this.

Comment: I am not sure but isn't it a dense layer and fully connected later is same.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  In the last few lines of your code that are tf.layers.dense, those are fully connected layers.  I re-read your code and it actually has 2 densely connected layers.  One has an activation of ReLU and the other one has none.  For your last layer, change the units from  1 to 40 and it should do regression.  The only difference between classification and regression is that classification uses a softmax or logistic activation to squash all the values between 0 - 1, whereas regression skips this part.